# how can i solve a system with inexact coefficients

Tags: equation-solving, warning-messages

I try to solve this system:

```
e1 = H1[0, y] - H1[0, Y]
e2 = H2[0, y] - H2[0, Y]
```

with

```
H1[x_, y_] = 8 (-0.1` x - 1.2` y) + (4 x - 0.8` y)^2 + 4 y^2;
H2[x_, y_] = (
  1 - 2 (1.5` - 0.5` x - 4.553076848028063`*^-15 y)^2 + 
   4 (-1.0344827586206884` - x + y)^2)/(1.5` - 0.5` x - 
    4.553076848028063`*^-15 y)^4;
```

I use `Solve` like this:

```
Solve[{e1, e2} == 0, {y, Y}]
```

but I found this message

Solve::ratnz: Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients. The answer was obtained by solving a corresponding exact system and numericizing the result. >>

Comment: You need a semicolon between your lines.

Comment: To form the exact system use [`Rationalize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rationalize.html). To force rationalization of all numeric values use `Rationalize[#, 0]&`

Comment: It says it ***solved*** the system and gave an answer....It gave me another warning, in effect that `Y == y` is solution in which `y` is a free variable.  In short, it worked! :) -- That said, coefficients that vary in magnitude by a factor of 10^15 is asking for numerical trouble.  That's an issue with how the problem is posed. `Ratioinalize` won't fix it, but it will show the uncertainty in a couple of the solutions, if you compare their numerical values. (I don't know how to fix it. How was `H2` derived?)

Comment: This will let you compare solutions side-by-side: `Sort /@ {{y, Y} /. Solve[{e1, e2} == 0, {y, Y}], {y, Y} /. Solve[Rationalize[{e1, e2}, 0] == 0, {y, Y}] // N} // Transpose // Grid`

Answer (score 1):

There is an extremely small number $a=4.553076848028063\times10^{-15}$ involved, which I'd treat with a lot of caution. Rationalizing all numbers except $a$, we have

```
H1[x_, y_] = 8 (-1/10 x - 12/10 y) + (4 x - 8/10 y)^2 + 4 y^2;
H2[x_, y_] = (1 - 2 (3/2 - 1/2 x - a y)^2 + 4 (-30/29 - x + y)^2)/(3/2 - 1/2 x - a y)^4;
```

and then

```
sol = Solve[{H1[0, y] - H1[0, Y] == 0, H2[0, y] - H2[0, Y] == 0}, {y, Y}];
```

The first solution is $y=Y$,

```
sol[[1]]
(*    {Y -> y}    *)
```

The remaining four solutions can be series-expanded for small $a$ to see their behavior:

```
Assuming[a > 0, Series[{y, Y} /. sol[[2]], {a, 0, 1}]] // FullSimplify
(*    {(30/29 + Sqrt[5]/4) - (9 Sqrt[5] a)/29 + O[a]^2,
       (30/29 - Sqrt[5]/4) + (9 Sqrt[5] a)/29 + O[a]^2}    *)
```

from which you can see that inserting an extremely small value of $a$ will give stable results $y\approx\frac{30}{29}+\frac{\sqrt{5}}{4}$ and $Y\approx\frac{30}{29}-\frac{\sqrt{5}}{4}$.

The third solution `sol[[3]]` is the same with $y$ and $Y$ interchanged.

The fourth solution diverges as $a\to0$,

```
Assuming[a > 0, Series[{y, Y} /. sol[[4]], {a, 0, 1}]] // FullSimplify
(*    (3 I)/(2 a) + (30/29 - (30 I)/29) + (3 I a)/4 + O[a]^2,
      -((3 I)/(2 a)) + (30/29 + (30 I)/29) - (3 I a)/4 + O[a]^2}    *)
```

and the fifth as well (with $y$ and $Y$ interchanged).

Comment: @MichaelE2 I  don't think your three-argument form of `Solve` gives an actual solution of the equations: back-substituting the suggested `{{Y -> 1/29 (60 - 29 y)}, {Y -> y}}` into the equations gives no match.

Comment: That may be; but notice that the solutions for $a=0$ are not the same as the solutions for $\lim_{a\to0^+}$. This is one of those cases where perturbing the equations is not the same as perturbing the solutions.